# Scrollable DIV inside table cell

Tags: html, css, layout, fixed

I know, my answer is a classic, but I cannot find proper solution, not here, nor using google. I'm trying to create layout using table. I wish the `table#layout` to be 100% of the screen (not more) and `#content-td` with scrolling. My solution works fine in FF/Chrome/Safari, but have some issues in IE. If `#content-td` has `height=100%` IE will set the height equals to table height (it's wrong, because I have `#header`). When I remove `height=100%` from `#content-td` IE will collapse this sell. Is there solution without javascript to fix div's height?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, #layout {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
            #wrapper {overflow-y:scroll; position:relative; height:100%}
            #content {position:absolute;}
            /* highlight areas */
            #header {background-color:#BADBAD;}
            #sidebar {background-color:#DABDAB;}
            #wrapper {background-color:#CD5C5C; font-size:40px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="layout" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr height="1%">
                <td colspan="2" id="header">Header</td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top" height="100%">
                <td id="content-td" width="70%" height="100%">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="content">
                            Here is long text I want to scroll down<br/>
                            Here is long text I want to scroll down<br/>
                            Here is long text I want to scroll down<br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="sidebar" width="30%">Sidebar</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine without doctype, but I want a valid document. Here is the [test page](http://satyrius.github.com/layout-with-scrolling-cell.html).

Comment: 'Some issues in IE.' I have heard that before, I just can't remember where…

Comment: @Time Machine: Yeah... I hear the `<b>` tag works in every browser except IE.

Comment: @Thanatos the b-tag shouldn't work anyway as it's deprecated.

Comment: Your test page looks fine in my IE - version 8.0.7600.16385

Answer (score -1):

I think your first mistake is wanting to use a table for layout.  I'm sure you know about the implications of that already, but if you don't, then it's probably worth searching the web for 'layout without tables'.

It sounds like the layout you're actually looking for is one where the main content scrolls as normal, but the side navigation pane is always in a fixed position on-screen.  An equivalent solution to your problem, funnily enough is to use `position:fixed` in CSS to keep the navigation in view.  For instance, you could make a main content box and a navigation box and use something like this (tested in Firefox):

```
body {margin-right:30%;}
#navigation {position:fixed; top:0; right:0; width:30%; height:100%; background:#fcc;}
```

If that isn't what you want, then provide a link to some example site or a diagram.

Comment: My first try was with `position:fixed` but it have been hampering scroll, especially in IE.

Comment: It's true that fixed positions don't work in IE6, but you can search Stack Overflow for solutions to that. What is this issue with 'hampering scroll'?